# How to dynamically choose environment in vsts release manager?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using vsts releases to manage our deployments.

I need to deploy to hundreds of instances, each one with at least two environments (UAT and prd).

Our pipeline looks like dev -> qa-> customer, where customer can be hundreds. So it is unmanageable to have two environments per client or to have one individual release definition per customer.

If I could dynamically change a variable for the customer environment at the moment the release is in progress, by user intervention on that variable, then I could have only one environment definition that could be used to deploy to any of my instances.

Does anyone has an idea of how to achieve that without a complex PowerShell? Is there anyway to dynamically change variables at run time in a vsts release?

Comment: Where does the new value come from which you want to updatefor the variable? And how do you want to use the modified variable value in UAT and prd environments?

Comment: Where the variable new value comes from is my doubt. I'm thinking of using a file that someone changes, then a powershell to set the variable with that content, which would be the value. Then, as it would be a variable I could use it in environments. If there was a feature like in build system, where you could change a variable before starting build, that would be great, but as far as I know that is not true for releases.

Comment: Yes, the feature is not available before deploying. And there has an user voice (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/16616269-change-release-variables-value-when-deploy-a-rele) for it, you can follow up.  Besides, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks Marina. I voted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging a little more, it turns out that the path I could follow is to change a variable on a specific release, and that make the tenants environment to use that variable to deploy to the correct target.

It actually is a workaround, because release don't have a way to define a variable value when creating a release from a release definition, like you can do in the build system.